# Limit the fields used by CMRESHandler

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logging

I am using CMRESHandler to emit my logs to elastic. However, it is creating a lot of fields by default. Here is a screenshot

[image: Fields added by CMRESHandler]

Is there anyway of limiting some of these default fields?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to first define `mappings for your index`.

---

Example: Create an `index` with name `cm-res-index`

Define the `mappings` with only the required fields. While defining the `mappings` use this setting `dynamic: false` => Reference is here => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html

So if you want only 2 fields like `host` & `time` this is how you do it :

```
PUT cm-res-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false, 
    "properties": {
      "host": { 
        "type": "text"
      },
      "time": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `dynamic` field if set to `false` will take care as to `not allow fields that are not defined in index mappings` .

---

Then start pushing data to your `elastic`.